# Evaluation order of multiplication operator and list indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I understand that multiplication operator in Python repeats the list based on the given integer.

Example:

```
x = 5*[8]
print(x)
```

The output will be

```
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

But however the below one produces `[40]`.

```
x = [5*[8][0]]
print(x)
```

How to interpret the above `x` definition?

Answer (score 2):

`[8]` is a list containing one value, 8.

`[8][0]` is the first element of that list, 8.

`5*[8][0]` is 5 multiplied by that value, 40.

`[5*[8][0]]` is a list containing that multiplication result, `[40]`.

The expression is evaluated in this order because of the operator precedence that is defined for the Python language:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from highest precedence (most binding) to lowest precedence (least binding). […]
>
> | Operator | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | … | … |
> | `x[index]`, … | Subscription, … |
> | … | … |
> | `*`, … | Multiplication, … |

i.e., `x[index]` has a higher precedence than `*` and is evaluated first.